Place 5 dominoes so that horizontal and vertical sums are equal
Arrange five different dominoes as in the diagram below such that adjacent squares of two different dominoes contain the same number of spots AND the total number of spots in the three horizontal dominoes is 5 AND the total number of spots in the two vertical dominoes is also 5.

Attribution:  Ian Stewart at The Prison Math Project, Spring 2024 newsletter, Problem D18.

I'm not sure "Ian Stewart" is sufficient attribution. Is it from a blog (link?), a book (title?), magazine article, etc?

@fljx I have added more detail to the attribution based on this Attribution help article.

Overall, up to reflection, I believe there are

 Four solutions

Some reasoning

 The four cells in the middle of the horizontal dominoes may only contain 0,1 or 2 to avoid going over 5.
 The number 1 cannot appear four times in the middle as it will mean a doubling of the domino 11. Both numbers 1 and 2 cannot appear together in the four middle cells as we will go over 5. If the number 0 appears four times, it means that the number at the ends will add up to 5 and the top numbers in the vertical dominoes also add up to 5 which will result in repeating dominoes.
 Crucially, this means that the number 0 must appear exactly twice in the four middle cells and either the number 1 or 2 must appear twice in the other two cells. It is easy to fill in the rest of the gaps from there in both cases.

Example of the first case

 
 This is actually the only solution here up to reflection, we get immediately that the left of the six middle cells cannot be 1 and the right of the six middle cells cannot be 0 leaving just two cases to check (0 on left and 3 on right or 2 on the left and 1 on the right). The first of these has the forced solution shown, the second is impossible to complete.

Example of the second case

 
 In this example, we must have that the extreme left of the six middle cells in 0 and the extreme right must be 1. This just leaves the bottoms of the vertical dominoes to fill in with them adding to 4. Legitimate possibilities are '4 and 0', '3 and 1' and '1 and 3' (pictured). Hence there are three solutions in this branch, up to reflection.


Here’s an answer, but I don’t think it’s the only one:

 


Cool, but how did you get it?  (Incidentally, I think it is the only answer.)

@msh210 it was just trial and error. And it’s certainly not the only one because I can exchange the two squares at the bottom without violating any requirements.

To find a solution to your question is easy. So instead, I will make an algorithm that creates all solutions.
Let's say that the formalization of a solution to this puzzle an ordered set of pairs $D = \{(x_1,y_1), \ (x_2, y_2), \ (x_3, y_3), \ (x_4, y_4), \ (x_5, y_5)\}$, where the pairs denote the dominoes left-to-right.

 In the three sideways dominoes, there are six squares which contain numbers $n \in \Bbb N_0$, and they are supposed to add up to $5$. The only way for this to happen is if there's at least one zero in those squares.

Given the nature of dominoes, we have the following fact:

 $$\forall x_i,y_i, \  y_i = x_{i+1}$$

Due to the puzzle, we have that:

 $$\sum_{i=2}^{n=4} x_i + y_i = 5 = x_1 + y_1 + x_5 + y_5$$


 So, we are looking for $D$s where the elements of its first and last pairs make up a weak $4$-composition of $5$, and where the elements of its middle four pairs make up a weak $6$-composition of $5$, and where the elements satisfy the aforementioned equalities.


 The set of all $D$s can be characterized by a number of restricted choices of some $x_i$s and $\ y_i$s, such that all of the other numbers are locked. The restriction will involve that $\forall x_i, y_i, \ x_i \le 5 \land y_i \le 5$.


 With that in mind, let us imagine filling in the domino grid, imagining the full range of choices at each step. I will give a rendering of this here, where every line centered on $\in$ represents a possible choice (possible, because sometimes one is choosing from a singleton), and where every line centered on $=$ represents the value being forced. $$ \begin{align} x_1 &\in \Bbb N_0^5 \\[2ex] y_1 &\in \Bbb N_0^{5-x_1} \\[2ex] x_2 &= y_1 \\[2ex] y_2 &\in \Bbb N_0^{\lfloor (5-y_1)/2 \rfloor} \\[2ex] x_3 &= y_2 \\[2ex] y_3 &\in \Bbb N_0^{\lfloor (5 - y_1 - 2y_2)/2 \rfloor} \\[2ex] x_4 &= y_3 \\[2ex] y_4 &= 5 - y_1 - 2y_2 -2y_3 \land y_4 \le 5 - x_1 -y_1 \\[2ex] x_5 &= y_4 \\[2ex] y_5 &= 5 - x_1 -y_1 - y_4 = 2(y_2 + y_3) - x_1 \end{align}$$


 In this rendering, we see that we have at most values that are chosen, given that there are only four $\in$s. There may be less if any of the featured sets are singletons. This rendering can be thought of as an algorithm for how to pick your values. As an algorithm, it may be incomplete however. The value $y_4$ has to satisfy two conditions. For some choices of previous calues, could these two conditions may be incompatible? Let's see:


 We restate the conditions on $y_4$ as a condition on the variables upon which it depends: $$5 - y_1 - 2y_2 -2y_3  \le 5 - x_1 -y_1 \implies 2(y_2 + y_3) \le x_1 $$


 With some reformulation, we can reformulate the above inequality as a possibly new, stricter upper-bounds on $y_2$ and $y_3$.


 We have that $y_2 \le x_1/2 - y_3$, which simply means $y_2 \le x_1/2$, because $y_3$ has not been picked yet, and it is allowed to equal zero. We also have $y_3 \le x_1/2 -y_2$. But looking at our original algorithm, we see it already satisfied these inequalities.

So, the algorithm to construct any solution to this puzzle is this:

 $$ \begin{align} x_1 &\in \Bbb N_0^5 \\[2ex] y_1 &\in \Bbb N_0^{5-x_1} \\[2ex] x_2 &= y_1 \\[2ex] y_2 &\in \Bbb N_0^{\lfloor (5-y_1)/2 \rfloor} \\[2ex] x_3 &= y_2 \\[2ex] y_3 &\in \Bbb N_0^{\lfloor (5 - y_1 - 2y_2)/2 \rfloor} \\[2ex] x_4 &= y_3 \\[2ex] y_4 &= 5 - y_1 - 2y_2 -2y_3  \\[2ex] x_5 &= y_4 \\[2ex] y_5 &= 2(y_2 + y_3) - x_1 \end{align}$$ $$ $$ $$D = \{(x_1,y_1), \ (x_2, y_2), \ (x_3, y_3), \ (x_4, y_4), \ (x_5, y_5)\}$$

Extra
How many solutions are there? Well, we just need to sum over all choices:

 $$\begin{align} S &= \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} \sum_{i_2=0}^{5-i_1} \sum_{i_3=0}^{\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor} \sum_{i_4 = 0}^{\lfloor (5-i_2-2i_3)/2 \rfloor} 1 \\[2ex] &=  \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} \sum_{i_2=0}^{5-i_1} \sum_{i_3=0}^{\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor} \lfloor (5-i_2-2i_3)/2 \rfloor + 1  \\[2ex] &=  \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} \sum_{i_2=0}^{5-i_1} \sum_{i_3=0}^{\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor} \lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor + 1 -i_3 \\[2ex] &=  \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} \sum_{i_2=0}^{5-i_1}  (\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor + 1)(\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor + 1) - \binom{\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor +1}{2} \\[2ex] &=  \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} \sum_{i_2=0}^{5-i_1}  2\binom{\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor +1}{2} - \binom{\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor +1}{2} + \lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor + 1 \\[2ex] &=  \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} \sum_{i_2=0}^{5-i_1}  \binom{\lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor +1}{2} + \lfloor (5-i_2)/2 \rfloor + 1 \\[2ex] &=  \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} 2 \binom{\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor +2}{3} - \binom{\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1}2 (i_1 \bmod 2) - 2\binom{\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1}3 + 2 \binom{\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor +2}{2} - (\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1)(i_1 \bmod 2) - 2\binom{\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1}2 \\[2ex] &=   \sum_{i_1=0}^{5} 8 - \binom{\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1}2 (i_1 \bmod 2) - 2\binom{\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1}3 + 12 - (\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1)(i_1 \bmod 2) - 2\binom{\lfloor i_1/2 \rfloor + 1}2 \\[2ex] &= 120 - \binom{\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor + 2}3  - 4\binom{\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor + 2}4 - 6 - 4\binom{\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor + 2}3  \\[2ex] &= 120 - 4  - 4 - 6 - 16 \\[2ex] &= 90 \end{align}$$


 I believe the thinking of the calculation above is correct, though due to the number of steps and their complexity, a few errors might have gotten in and made the number of solutions incorrect. Please feel free to point out any errors. Anyways, if the above is correct, we have 90 different solutions.


Are you taking into account that you cannot have duplicate dominos?

I don't think your second spoiler is correct. Only $y_i = x_{i+1}$ is required. $x_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ are not adjacent, and do not restrict each other.

@JaapScherphuis Oh nope... I kind of glanced over "different dominoes", just thinking "different" as in "separate". Frick...
